# jQuery Uncaught Exception Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

To check whether the email address is from gmail I tried the following jQuery code but I am getting  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined`

**CODE**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#sendit").click(
   function() {
      var str1 = $("#email").value;
      var str2 = "gmail.com";
      if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
        alert("found");
      }
   });
});
```

Is there any error in my syntax?

Comment: If you had an error in your syntax, you would get a *syntax error*. You are trying to access a non-existing property of an object (`.value`), which will return `undefined`. That's a *runtime error* and a logic error in your code (but not a syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R29xR/)

Call the `val()` method.

```
var str1 = $("#email").val();
```

---

May be you are victim of jQuery Conflict. See if the code in this new fiddle works for you.

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R29xR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
var str1 = $("#email").val();
```

`$("#email")` returns a jQuery wrapper object, it does not have the `value` property, it belongs to dom element. jQuery object has a method [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) that returns the value.

Comment: @lock is there an element with id `email`

Comment: @lock can you share the html related to the element `email`

Comment: I just tried the this code `$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#userid").click(
   function() {
      var str1 = $("#email").val();
      var str2 = "karthik";
      if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
     alert("found");
      }
   });
});` at http://jcubbooklinx.com/wp-login.php?action=login

Comment: there are other errors in the page... check your browser console

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val()` instead of `value`

Change

```
var str1 = $("#email").value;
```

to

```
var str1 = $("#email").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use val(), instead of value

```
var str1 = $("#email").val()
```